# SQL server - traverse tree in two directions

Tags: sql, sql-server, tree, common-table-expression

Say I have a tree-structured table of regions:

```
id     parent_id      name
---------------------------------
1      null           Europe
2      1              Germany
3      2              Köln
4      2              Berlin
5      1              Norway
```

Now I want to manage access rights at any node in the tree. Access rights pertain to documents and users. I've figured that I can use a recursive CTE to get all nodes at or below a given node. For instance, users with access to "Germany" should have access to all documents shared with "Germany", "Köln" or "Berlin", which is simple enough.

However, I'm lost when I want to traverse the tree in both directions. A user in Germany should also see a document that is shared with "Europe". A user in Köln should be able to see "Köln", "Germany" and "Europe", but not "Berlin".

```
WITH RegionTree AS (
    SELECT topRegion.Id RootId, topRegion.Name, topRegion.Id
    FROM Region topRegion
    UNION ALL
    SELECT rt.RootId, r.Name, r.Id
    FROM Region r
    INNER JOIN RegionTree rt ON rt.Id = r.ParentId
)
SELECT rt.RootId, rt.Name, rt.Id
FROM RegionTree rt
WHERE rt.RootId = 2
```

This query yields "Germany", "Köln", "Berlin", starting from the node "Germany" going up, but I would like to run a query that yields all these nodes, plus any number of nodes going up, but not branching out, from "Germany".

Would I need to create two CTEs and query both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform a `UNION` on 2 `CTE` result set that work both up and down the tree.

So the join in CTE1 would be:

```
INNER JOIN RegionTree rt ON rt.Id = r.ParentId
```

And the join on CTE2 would be the other way round to work in reverse:

```
INNER JOIN RegionTree2 rt ON rt.ParentId = r.Id
```

So performing a `UNION` on the CTE results, (sorry it's untested)

```
WITH RegionTree AS (
    SELECT topRegion.Id RootId, topRegion.Name, topRegion.Id
    FROM Region topRegion
    UNION ALL
    SELECT rt.RootId, r.Name, r.Id
    FROM Region r
    INNER JOIN RegionTree rt ON rt.Id = r.ParentId
),
RegionTree2 AS (
    SELECT topRegion.Id RootId, topRegion.Name, topRegion.Id
    FROM Region topRegion
    UNION ALL
    SELECT rt.RootId, r.Name, r.Id
    FROM Region r
    INNER JOIN RegionTree2 rt ON rt.ParentId = r.Id
)
SELECT rt.RootId, rt.Id, rt.Name, rt.CustomerId, rt.EntityId, rt.Depth
FROM RegionTree rt
WHERE rt.RootId = 2
UNION
SELECT rt.RootId, rt.Id, rt.Name, rt.CustomerId, rt.EntityId, rt.Depth
FROM RegionTree2 rt
WHERE rt.RootId = 2
```

Looking at the query though, I would possibly modify the CTE's to include the filter condition rather than how it is currently in the `WHERE` clause, to prevent querying more data than is required. Something like this:

```
DECLARE @ID INT = 2

WITH RegionTree AS (
    SELECT topRegion.Id RootId, topRegion.Name, topRegion.Id
    FROM Region topRegion
    WHERE topRegion.Id = @ID  --ADDED
    UNION ALL
    SELECT rt.RootId, r.Name, r.Id
    FROM Region r
    INNER JOIN RegionTree rt ON rt.Id = r.ParentId
    WHERE topRegion.Id IS NOT NULL -- ADDED
),
RegionTree2 AS (
    SELECT topRegion.Id RootId, topRegion.Name, topRegion.Id
    FROM Region topRegion
    WHERE topRegion.Id = @ID  --ADDED
    UNION ALL
    SELECT rt.RootId, r.Name, r.Id
    FROM Region r
    INNER JOIN RegionTree2 rt ON rt.ParentId = r.Id
    WHERE topRegion.Id IS NOT NULL -- ADDED
)
SELECT rt.RootId, rt.Id, rt.Name, rt.CustomerId, rt.EntityId, rt.Depth
FROM RegionTree rt
UNION
SELECT rt.RootId, rt.Id, rt.Name, rt.CustomerId, rt.EntityId, rt.Depth
FROM RegionTree2 rt
```